# Is a UIScrollView’s contentOffset relative to contentInset

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Say I set a UIScrollview’s `contentInset.top` to say `100`, and then the `contentOffset.y` to `0` .

If I had an element positioned in the scroll view with `frame.y = 0`, ahold I expect this element to be at the top of the scroll view, or 100px down?

Answer (score 0):

According to your settings , it will be 100pt down , as the frame.y = 0 is being calculated relative to

First top view in the

```
topView.y = contentInset.top + contentOffset.y
```